# Pytorch - Gradient distribution between functions

Tags: gradient-descent, pytorch

https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/tutorials/blob/gh-pages/_downloads/neural_networks_tutorial.ipynb

Hi I am trying to understand the NN with pytorch. 
I have doubts in gradient calculations..

import torch.optim as optim

```
create your optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

```
# in your training loop:
optimizer.zero_grad()   # zero the gradient buffers
output = net(input)
loss = criterion(output, target)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()    # Does the update
```

From the about code, I understood loss.backward() calculates the gradients. 
I am not sure, how these info shared with `optimizer` to update the gradient.

Can anyone explain this..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Recall that you passed `net.parameters()` to the optimizer, so it has access to the "Tensor" objects, as well as their associated data. One of the associated data fields associated to each *learnable* tensor parameter is a *gradient buffer*. Hence, `backward()` not only computes the gradients, but *stores them in each parameter tensor*, so that the gradient vector per parameter is stored along with that parameter. In other words, for some parameter $\theta_i$, `backward()` stores $ \partial \mathcal{L}(\Theta)/\partial \theta_i$ along with that parameter. The `optimizer.step()` call then simply updates each parameter via the gradient stored along with it.